# Instagram API access token generation throws "You must provide a client_id" error even though I provided one

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Generating an access token for the Python Instagram API requires running [this file](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/blob/master/get_access_token.py) and then entering a Client ID, Client Secret, Redirect URI, and Scope. The console then outputs a URL to follow to authorize the app and asks for the code generated afterwards. Theoretically after this process it should return an access token.

Instead, it's throwing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_access_token.py", line 40, in <module>
    access_token = api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Leybzon\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 48, in exchange_code_for_access_token
    return req.exchange_for_access_token(code=code)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel Leybzon\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\instagram\oauth2.py", line 115, in exchange_for_access_token
    raise OAuth2AuthExchangeError(parsed_content.get("error_message", ""))
instagram.oauth2.OAuth2AuthExchangeError: You must provide a client_id
```

Screenshot provided for context:[image]